# Magento: Get all configured rates of the tablerate shipping module

Tags: magento

I'm stuck on what I think should be a minor problem, but I couldn't find a solution yet.

I'm working on a module that has to go through all configured rates of the tablerate shipping module. But how do I get all configured rates, and not just the one that fits a given condition? I looked into the code of the corresponding resource model ("shipping/carrier_tablerate"), and saw that the getRate($request)-method limits the select query to 1, so only 1 rate is returned.

Is there an easy way to get all configured rates? Is there a built-in way to do this at all or do I have to perform my own database operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$tablerateColl = Mage::getResourceModel('shipping/carrier_tablerate_collection');
/* @var $tablerateColl Mage_Shipping_Model_Resource_Carrier_Tablerate_Collection */

foreach ($tablerateColl as $tablerate) {
    /* @var $tablerate Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate */
    Zend_Debug::dump($tablerate->debug());
}
```